# C# create proto file from c# class

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to generate protobuf file from my c# class for some external collaboratosr.
The issue is: i have many nullable value (int?, double?)

but when i doing this :

```
string protoOutput = Serializer.GetProto<Test>();
```

with class

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Test
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int? TEST { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public DateTime SDF { get; set; }
}
```

the proto serializer output is:

```
 syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Test {
   int32 TEST = 1;
   .google.protobuf.Timestamp SDF = 2;
}
```

how can i configure the serializer in order to have a :

```
google.protobuf.Int32Value
```

for my int? property

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

protobuf-net does not currently advertise data as `Int32Value`, and even if it did: that isn't how `int?` gets encoded, so: that would be bad.

What we *should* perhaps do here, however, is make use of the (fairly recent) proto3 presence tracking feature (which didn't exist when that code was last touched). To explain this manually, this means: "add `optional`", i.e.

```cs
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message Test {
   optional int32 TEST = 1;
   .google.protobuf.Timestamp SDF = 2;
}
```

which provides a mechanism to detect "no value", while still being wire-compatible with the relevant encoding. For today, I would say: add `optional` by hand.

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell thanks for the answer so that's mean Int32Value provided by wrapper.proto is not a real equivalent ?

Comment: @A.Caillet correct; it is a real equivalent of *something*, but it has a different encoded structure to how `int?` would be encoded by protobuf-net, which is more like an `int32` which may or may not be there. Keep in mind: wrapper.proto dates to 2015 - protobuf-net dates to something like 2008? 2009? so: it isn't surprising that it didn't elect to use that particular layout. But: what *matters* is that you can detect presence or lack thereof - which adding `optional` achieves in proto3 (note: in proto2, presence tracking was always present for `optional`)

Comment: Thanks for your time - i will go this way then.